# Efficient way to reverse three consecutive subranges [A,B,C] -> [C,B,A]

Tags: c++, stl, stl-algorithm

I've got an array [A,B,C] consisting of three consecutive sub-arrays A, B and C. I'd like to reverse the larger array into [C,B,A]. My current attempt involves thee calls to `std::rotate`, as shown below. I wonder if there is a more straightforward/efficient way to achieve this, preferably using an std algorithm.

```
Step 1: "swap" sub-array B,C
[A,B,C] -> [A|B,C] -> [A,C,B]

Step 2: "swap" sub-array A,C
[A,C,B] -> [A,C|B] -> [C,A,B]

Step 3: "swap" sub-array A,B
[C,A,B] -> [C|A,B] -> [C,B,A]
```

**Edit**

For example given the array `[1,2,3|4,5,6|7,8,9]` I would like to "reverse" it into `[7,8,9|4,5,6|1,2,3]`

[Sample implementation](http://rextester.com/MGUY61030). Please note that the sizes of the "ranges" are merely illustrative.

Comment: Do you have a flat array or array of 3 arrays? Because if it's the latter, just use `std::reverse`

Comment: *How* do you have "an array"? What are the "sub-arrays"? Is it an array of arrays? A vector of vectors? A single array where you arbitrarily split it up into "sub-arrays"? Please give us more details. Preferably a  [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @krzaq please refer to my edit

Comment: Is it really just a 3x3 matrix of ints? Or can it be NxN? 9 ints are probably 36 bytes. Assuming it is aligned correctly, you should get all of them in one cache line so the algorithm used to do the swaps should be relatively insignificant as long as you are getting the data all at once. If it is NxN, you'll have to think about optimizing around grabbing 64 byte chunks (typical cache line size) and swapping groups of those.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg See OP for minimal example.

Comment: What's wrong with [std::swap_ranges](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap_ranges)?

Comment: @graham.reeds ... Absolutely nothing. In fact, it looks like the most efficient of all the solutions put forth  -- which is why I asked this question in the fisr place because my spider senses told me that the standard library might have a better solution. because . Please  consider posting this as an answer.

Comment: @graham.reeds Oh wait both ranges in `std::swap_ranges` apparently seem to need to have the same size. My data provides no such guarantee :-( .

Comment: Are you asking just for fun? You are trying to find an algorithm for a data type; could you try to find a data type for your algorithm? I wonder what the objective of your question is actually?

Comment: @Elyasin Please refer to my minimal example http://rextester.com/MGUY61030 . I already have an implementation that uses three calls to `std::rotate` and I'd like to know if there is a more efficient implementation.

Comment: Saw it already. Nothing wrong with it.

Comment: @Elyasin Then what made ask wonder about "the objective of my question" and if I'm "asking just for fun"?? ... `std::swap_ranges` would have been perfect if not for the equality restriction on the input ranges. BTW, I regard the three consecutive calls in my original implementation seems to be a bit of a code smell.

Comment: @Olumide How large are the data sets you are hoping to swap?

Comment: @RyanP It varies but generally each subrange is over a thousand bytes. Your idea about optimizing for cache size is interesting but I tend to first consider more efficient algorithms before lower-level optimizations. So no I'm not working with a matrix of 3x3 ints in spite of what my example may suggest.

Comment: That's it. "Nothing wrong with it". You have an array and swap elements till they have the order you want. Whether you swap or rotate or move the elements otherwise is cosmetics in my opinion. It is only one array, probably not very large; not much you can significantly optimize here.

Comment: @Olumide Fair enough, but with modern processors most of your time is spent waiting for data from main memory so it is worth looking into. I've seen functions that corner turned large arrays run 4x faster with just basic optimizations around the cache line size, I'm sure you could do better.

Comment: @Elyasin you clearly missed out the part where I said **"Please note that the sizes of the 'ranges' are merely illustrative."** Its a minimal example. Each subrange in my actual program is thousands of bytes.

Comment: @RyanP Your point is valid and acknowledged. I just think that efficient algorithms should be considering before lower level techniques which may or may not be portable with different hardware and compilers. Note that I'm not saying that your approach is not valid, rather that it should be considered after the best available algorithm is implemented, which is what I am currently striving for.

Comment: 1000s of bytes is not really large. Unless you execute the piece of code very frequently, I don't see a need to optimise.

Comment: @Elyasin The frequency of execution of the code or the data size was not part of the question. If I start to introduce more about the specifics of the problem domain it would become an entire different question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reverse the whole array then reverse each subarray.

```
[1,2,3|4,5,6|7,8,9]
[9,8,7|6,5,4|3,2,1]
[7,8,9|4,5,6|1,2,3]
```

This will take two linear passes and is extremely CPU cache friendly.

Comment: [C++ implementation of this algorithm](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/49175b99dd126192)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version with Ranges V3:

```
array<int, 9> arr = {{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}};

auto v = view::chunk(arr, 3) | view::reverse | view::join;

array<int, 9> reversed;
ranges::copy(v, reversed.begin());

for(int n : arr) cout << n << ' '; cout << '\n';
for(int n : reversed) cout << n << ' '; cout << '\n';
```

Prints:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
7 8 9 4 5 6 1 2 3
```

Can't say much about performance, but it didn't compile quickly for me.

Comment: Where is `DBG_CONT` defined?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews it's a hacky macro that I sometimes use. Edited it out.